# Processing array in smarty

Tags: arrays, loops, smarty

I am trying to access an array in smarty using section command. I would like to iterate 1-128 using a section command in smarty , but the main thing is that the loop must be 65. Now I can access the indexes up to 64 using $smarty.section.foo.index. I would like to access the values in the indexes > 64 using a constant as  {$lan.printer[$smarty.section.foo.index]+64}. But it is not working . Please help me to solve this .

My code is as follows

```
{section name=foo start=1 loop=65 step=1}
       {$lan.printer[$smarty.section.foo.index]}
       {$lan.printer[$smarty.section.foo.index]+64}
{/section}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the obvious typo in your code, to use an expression as an index into an array, you need to assign it to a variable first, so that it can be referenced:

```
{section name=foo start=1 loop=65 step=1}
   {assign var=offsetIndex value=$smarty.section.foo.index+64}
   {$lan.printer[$smarty.section.foo.index]}
   {$lan.printer[$offsetIndex]}
{/section}
```